# JS filter function issue

Tags: javascript, function, filter

```
function filter() {
  var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  var array2 = array1.filter(function(n) {
    return array1[n] = 1;
  });

  console.log(array2);
}

filter();
```

This function returns an array with the following values:

```
[1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 9]
```

and I don't understand why? Can Someone Explain This For Me, Please

Comment: You're assigning rather than comparing `array1[n] == 1;`  Furthermore, I don't understand your logic.

Comment: `array1[n] = 1` or `array1[n] == 1`?

Comment: The first argument passed to the callback is the *array item* being iterated over, not the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
 array Index =[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

var array2 = array1.filter(function (n) {

```
    return array1[n] = 1;
});
```

step 1:

array1.filter(function (1) { //first value of array1

```
    return array1[1] = 1; // you assigning the  index 1 of array as 1
});
```

output: now array1 will look like this:  [1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

step 2:

array1.filter(function (1) { //second value of array1 is 1

```
    return array1[1] = 1; // you assigning the  index 1 of array as 1
});
```

now array1 will look like this:  [1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

step 2:

array1.filter(function (3) { //third value of array1

```
    return array1[3] = 1; // you assigning the index 3 of array as 1
});
```

now array1 will look like this:  [1,1,3,1,5,6,7,8,9]

Similarly, this will be applied for a remaining array values

Answer (score 4):

That's because `return array1[n] = 1;` always returns true and every element is getting returned for every case.Change it too `===`.